# Is there a way of persisting localstorage or another method of storage when you visit a PWA through a mobile browser and then installing it

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, progressive-web-apps, session-storage

I think essentially what I am asking here in a practical sense is, using ReactJS is there a way you can load the PWA on a mobile browser, store a variable in localstorage or similar, then immediately after this, installing the app to the device, run the app from the 'home screen' and be able to access the same stored data.

For example:
Load app on mobile browser,
Enter your name in an input field.
Hit 'Save' button and store that variable.
Have the variable render out in a component/underneath the input etc.
Install the app to the mobile device.
Open app on mobile.
See your name persisting.

^^

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of articles which could help my situation. If these work I will close the Q.

https://www.netguru.com/codestories/how-to-share-session-cookie-or-state-between-pwa-in-standalone-mode-and-safari-on-ios

https://jakub-kozak.medium.com/how-to-share-state-data-between-a-pwa-in-ios-safari-and-standalone-mode-64174a48b043